# Display the gap between values on the x axis based on how much or how little the each individual data differs between them

Tags: angular, datetime, chart.js, primeng

Hello I have an angular app and I am using primeng p-chart which uses chartjs. The x axis is represented by date time data and is looks something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcpeB.png) What I want to achive is the following. Lets say that two points in the x axis differ by some seconds in this case they should be displayed near between them on the other hand if data has a huge difference by minutes or even days they should be far apart. Until now the data is distributed equally. I searched in the official documentation and found the following: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html but it did not help me. Could someone give me some suggestions how can I achieve this or where should I start.

Comment: I think you need to use time axis. Why didn't it help you?

Comment: I used it, the only difference is it displays the data in a different format like this: 12:59:59:999am and I understand you can modify the format ect. But I just wanted to visualize the gap not symmetrically. I don't know if I am clear enough sorry XD

Comment: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/MWPqexK As you can see on codepen, the data points have got different distances based on the time. And afaik this is possible only with time scale.

Comment: Yes I see and thank you for the codepen link I appreciate that but my requirements are as follow: lets say from the DB I get 05/16/2023 12:41:36, 05/16/2023 12:41:54, 05/16/2023 12:45:22. The distances between these data from one another should be by comparing even second in a way that if they differ by small seconds they should be near and if they differ by minutes or hours they should be more apart from each other.